# Stable Picard group of the tensor product of two Hopf algebras

Tags: hopf-algebras, picard-group, stable-category

Suppose we know the stable Picard groups (=Picard group of the stable module category) of two cocommunicative Hopf $k$-algebras $G$ and $H$. Is it possible to deduce the stable Picard group of $G\otimes_kH$ from them?

Comment: I don't think so. For example for $A=B=\mathbb{F}_2[C_2]$, the respective Picard groups are trivial, but for $A\otimes B$ the Picard group is given by $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AchimKrause Great Couterexample! Thanks!